# PopUp is not opening on mousehover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure what i am doing wrong here.i have a div and i want to open up a popup if user hover over that div section and want to close on mouseout. here is my code

```
<div class="topCart">
  some data
</div>
```

this is my JQuery code

```
$(".topCart").mouseover(function() {
    $.get('${rolloverPopupUrl}?bustcache=' + new Date().getTime(),
     function(result) {
        $('#viewCart').html(result);
        refreshMiniCart();
        });
    $('#viewCart').slideDown('slow');
    }).mouseout(function() {
     $('#viewCart').slideUp('fast');
   });
```

above code is not working nor its giving any Ajax call to fetch fresh data, while if i use following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".topCart").hover( function () {
    $('#viewCart').html("");
    $.get('${rolloverPopupUrl}?bustcache='+new Date().getTime(), function(result){
    $('#viewCart').html(result);
     refreshMiniCart();
    });
     if($('#viewCart').is(':hidden')){
        $('#viewCart').slideDown('slow'); }
        },
        function () {
            $('#viewCart').slideUp('fast');
        });
});
```

this piece of code is working and its fetching data so i do not see use of `document.ready`
with my limited knowledge of Jquery i tried but not able to see the reason of not working of code
can any one point me my error?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Any errors?

Comment: @zomboble: i took help from firebug and it showing no error on console

Comment: You will need the document.ready method as otherwise it will not execute the function you have, i'm struggling to understand the question sorry

Comment: @zomboble well my question was, is it required to put that under document.ready and if yes why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try having some basic structure and cleanliness (which is next to godliness) when typing your code, and spotting errors will be much easier:

```
$(function() {
    $(".topCart").on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            var elem = $('#viewCart');
            elem.empty();        
            $.get('${rolloverPopupUrl}?bustcache=' + new Date().getTime(), function(result) {
                elem.html(result);
                refreshMiniCart();
            });
            if (!elem.is(':visible')) elem.slideDown('slow');
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $('#viewCart').slideUp('fast');
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, when i am using above code a lot of flickering occurring on cart pop-up, i am not sure what might be the cause of this

Answer (score 0):

The first code does not work becuse not all DOM elements are downloaded when you set events.  And it cause that result of `$(".topCart")` is empty. This not fire any erros, syntax is correct, problem is jQuery works with html, that are not completed.

`$(document).ready(...)`

or

```
$(function() {
 // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".topCart").mouseover(function() {
        ...
    }
});
```

You need to use the document.ready before events can fire, after the document all DOM elements have loaded which you can be sure of, otherwise you're looking for an event which hasnt laoded into the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Without the `$(document).ready()`, the first has not actually been bound to `$('.topCart')`.

The second example, using the document ready gives a moment or time at which to bind the function to the hover event.